# Javascript to change div width dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Can anyone help me out to create a javascript?

Let me explain, i have 2 divs

1) left div width 85%
2) right div width 15%

so there is what i want to change width for left div. like, if i remove or hide right div, left div width should 100% dynamically with javascrpt.

Comment: Without code in here, people don't find easy to answer your question. [Create Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: you guys also can see what i am trying to do http://client-acumenadagency.com/sed/

Comment: this div need to be full width if the other div hide

<div id="Resize" class="content-left"></div>

and the other div is 

<div id="button" class="navbar right"></div>

Comment: I would recommend you don't do this with JavaScript. Do it with CSS instead. Only use JavaScript to set the classes.

Comment: @Halcyon how can i do it with css? can you help me out plz

Comment: Lots of ways you could do it with CSS. [Here's one](https://jsfiddle.net/Lme30fpp/).

Answer (score 3):

I have done it using JavaScript:

[WORKING : Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/x04kgjpm/1/)

[UPDATED : Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/x04kgjpm/2/)

[UPDATED : Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/x04kgjpm/4/) : Animate slide in/out with CSS transitions.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="div1"></span><span class="div2"></span>

</div>
<button>Remove</button>
```

**CSS : UPDATED**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.div1 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:85%;
    height:40px;
    background:#333;
}
.div2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:15%;
    height:40px;
    background:green;
}
 /*ADDED BELOW LINES*/

 .div1, .div2
 {
  /* Change Seconds(here it's 0.5s) as per your requirement */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }

 .addRemoveContent
 {
   width:100%;
 }

 .addRemoveMenu
 {
   width:0;
 }
```

**JS**

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".div2").hide(10);
    $(".div1").css("width", "100%");

});
```

**JS:UPDATED** - Bringing right div back

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".div2").toggleClass("addRemoveMenu");
    $(".div1").toggleClass("addRemoveContent");

});
```

Comment: you did a nice job but can you please make it more useable for me on click to button, right side will come show again.

Can you help me out?

Comment: If still any issues feel free to ask!

Comment: Great that it worked for you! If this answer was helpful you could accept this answer. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it damn working now and it's only you to resolve my issue

Comment: Sorry for asking again and again, but if you find this answer helpful, i request you to accept this answer(only if helpful). [See Here](http://divyashah.in/img.jpg), as you new in here.

Comment: can you help me out to make my website more attractive? 
See i have done with button hide and show on right as you helped me before now i want to make it slide like when some one click on toggle button, right bar should hide and show as a smooth slid. I hope you got my point.

here is the JQ which i modified

Comment: @HMSDesignz let me see first, give me link.

Comment: you did amazing job but can we also slide right menu bar smoothly?

you can visit same link
http://client-acumenadagency.com/sed/

Comment: @HMSDesignz the problem is in your html/js code. See this [image](http://www.divyashah.in/stackoverflow/12.png)

Comment: See this is the script what i am using

$("button").click(function () {
    var getDivStyle = document.getElementById('div2').style.display;
    if(getDivStyle == 'block')
    {
    $(".navbar.right").hide(10);
    $(".content-left").css("width", "100%");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".navbar.right").show(10);
    $(".content-left").css("width", "85%");
    }
 
 
 $(".navbar.right").toggleClass("addRemoveMenu");
    $(".content-left").toggleClass("addRemoveContent");

});

Comment: @HMSDesignz Why do you need this? after all you are already using toggleClass two lines of code. Try it after removing and just keep those two toggleClass line's

Comment: Sorry which one two lines?

Comment: I have removed but still right menu bar is moving suddenly i want to move it smooth like left side so can we do that?

Comment: yes, do me a favor could i get access to your all html and css files somewhere, will check it out when free

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo for the CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/yf3e5bhv/

The advantage of this approach is that your template is declarative. You could make a plain HTML page of each state of your application. In my opinion this greatly aids development and maintenance.

---

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="toggle" id="button" /><br /><br />
<div id="left"></div><div id="right"></div>
```

CSS

```
#left, #right {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
body.hide-right #right {
    display: none;
}
body.hide-right #left {
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
var state = false;
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var classname = "";
    if (state === false) {
        classname = "hide-right";
    }
    document.body.className = classname;
    state = !state;
});
```

You can significantly reduce this code if you use a library like jQuery:

```
$("#button").on("click", function () {
    $(document.body).toggleClass("hide-right");
});
```

Comment: Hello Dear @Halcyon,

Thanks a lot to help me but there is a problem like as you divided left and right div in 50% but i need left div 85% and left 15% 

so how can i do it with your code?

Comment: Just change the values in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS and JavaScript. Quick and dirty way:

```
.dynamic {
     margin-right: 0;
}
```

Set your divs to have a margin-right, then use JavaScript to apply this class whenever the div is hidden.

```
function hideDiv(id, outerdiv) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'; //hide the right div
  $("#outdiv").addClass("dynamic"); //make the other div fill the space
}
```